# Gradle error when using the android studio preview build for java 8

Tags: android-studio, java-8

I downloaded the android studio 2.4 preview 6. It has support for java 8 without using jack. This is my application gradle filebuildscript {

```
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha6'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  description 'Creates the gradle wrapper.'
  gradleVersion '2.8'
}
```

And this is my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Thu Apr 13 15:20:48 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

But I keep getting the error :

```
Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.tooling.model.gradle.GradleBuild.getIncludedBuilds()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/DomainObjectSet;'
```

What could be leading to the error and how can I solve it? I have tried invalidate cache/restart.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me. If you're going to use a beta build you shouldn't rely much on it for reasons like this; it's too buggy. Downgrade to the older version if you're going to push something to production or sell it, and if you're just looking at the new features, change to an older/newer preview. Android studio isn't known for being built that well.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Alex, I had mostly all the same versions as you:

Dependencies: Grade 2.4.0-alpha6
Gradle Wrapper: gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
Android Studio 2.4 preview 7

Had exactly the same error after updating from Android Studio 2.4 preview 1.

I got off the Canary channel and downloaded stable version 2.3.1 - Problem solved.

I might try a preview again in a couple months but I've found the last couple to be super buggy.